# How to substitute a string with a digit and a capture group?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string containing a digit that I want to replace with another one and retain the rest of the string.

e.g.,

original = `VAR token       3`

modified = `VAR token       1 // orig = 3`

the `token` can be any string, the statement always starts with `VAR` and contains whitespace between the `token` and its value.

I am using this function and regular expression

```
import re

def modify(line, token, new_value):
    newline = re.sub(r'(^(\s*VAR\s*%s\s+)(\d+)(.*)' % token, r'\1%s // orig = \2\3' % new_value, line)
    print(newline)
```

I receive an error when running this code with

```
modify("VAR T    3", "T", "1")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/3.4.3_wTclTk/lib/python3.4/sre_parse.py", line 866, in expand_template
    literals[index] = s = g(group)
IndexError: no such group

<Stack Trace>
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
```

I assume it is because the replacement string is actually becomes `r'\11 // orig = \2\3'` and there is no group `11`.

How can I define the literal digit separately from the group identifier in the replacement string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import re

def modify(line, token, new_value):
    newline = re.sub(r'^(VAR\s*)({}\s*)(\s+)(\d+)'.format(token), r'\1\2 {} // orig = \4'.format(new_value), line)
    print(newline)

modify("VAR T    3", "T", "1")
```

**Output:**

```
VAR T    1 // orig = 3
```

Comment: I will update my question - the amount of whitespace between the token and value should be retained...

Comment: try: `newline = re.sub(r'^(VAR\s*)({}\s*)(\s+)(\d+)'.format(token), r'\1\2 {} // orig = \4'.format(new_value), line)`